# redshift procedure with out parameter and dynamic table name as in parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I'm trying to make a redshift procedure that will give output on any table like say a row count for example.  But I can't figure out how you are supposed to pass in a table name dynamically and get output.  I'm trying to do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_schea.test(t in varchar, o out varchar) 
LANGUAGE plpgsql 
AS $$ 
BEGIN  execute 'SELECT count(*) into ' || o || ' FROM ' || t || ';';
               -- or something more complicated
 END  
$$ ;
```

then I call like this:

```
call my_schema.test('myschema.mytable');
```

I can't seem to get the syntax right,  any help would be appreciated.
this specific syntax above gives me an error of:

```
 cannot EXECUTE a null query string;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to change.

- `out o varchar` is invalid; `out` parameters are not allowed in procedures, only `inout` ;
- `into o` does not work in dynamic sql because it does not 'see' the local variables. See [execute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html).

So the procedure sample becomes -

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_schema.test(in t text, inout o bigint default null)  as
$$
begin
   execute ('SELECT count(*) FROM '||t) into o; -- NB *** SQLi prone ***
   -- or something more complicated
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Then you can

```sql
call my_schema.test('myschema.mytable');
```

and it will yield a result similar to that of a `select` statement.
I assume that you have a good reason to write a procedure and not a function since the example looks very much like one. As a function the sample would look like this:

```sql
create or replace function my_schema.testf(t text) returns bigint  as
$$
declare 
   retval bigint;
begin
   execute ('SELECT count(*) FROM '||t) into retval; -- NB *** SQLi prone ***
   -- or something more complicated
   return retval;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

and then

```sql
select my_schema.testf('myschema.mytable');
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answering this question.  I've given this a try and two things.  First I don't think you can write Redshift functions in plpgsql see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html.    Second,  I'm not able to get the stored procedure create query to run either.   I get an error with the 'default'  yet even when i remove the ```default null``` I still get a ```syntax error at or near ```.  So something is not quoted right

Comment: Well, these are working procedure and function but in Postgresql. I am afraid that I can not help much with Redshift dialect.Yet try `o out bigint` or integer, w/o default. I see that the syntax differs a bit.